# JavaFX - Scroll Bar missing from WebView until I move mouse over where it should be

Tags: java, css, javafx, webview

I'm running into an issue where the scroll bar in my WebView is not showing up until I move my mouse over the spot that it should be.

This is my java code

```
browser = new WebView();
        browser.setId(SidePanelPageFields.BROWSER);

        webEngine = browser.getEngine();
        webEngine
            .setUserStyleSheetLocation(getClass().getResource("/style.css").toString());
```

And this is my CSS

```
body {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

For the CSS, I've tried changing overflow to visible. I've tried

```
.scroll-bar {
    display: show
}
```

Nothing has worked so far. Any idea how to make the scroll bar show up on initialization? Thanks!

Comment: On OS X, this is a feature controlled in `System Preferences > General`.

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment was in reference to. This is a Java program that I'm coding using JavaFX and the scroll bar in the WebView of the Java program is not showing up until I move my mouse over where it should be.

Comment: I thought you might be on OS X; if not, I'm curious which other host platform has this feature.